# Design overlap button in angular

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEYDO.jpg) I am trying to design button or nav like this to show diff div on click but unable to found how i can do it.I have try to create diff button but unable to overlap it. Is this any good way to do this in bootstrap. Thanks in advance don make it duplicate please

```
<label class="" onclick="">
   <input type="checkbox" checked />
     <span>
        <span>Previous</span>
        <span>Upcoming</span>
     </span>
<a></a>
</label>
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a "we code it for you" site. We can help you if you post your code and tell us where exactly you are stuck tough.

Comment: @cloned I am using checkbox but confused on css but I am a backend developer. never be in this situation.